# how to determine the type of string

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am getting the following error when writing into a sql-alchemy varchar string element

```
....You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str)....
```

How can I determine the type of a string in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`8-bit bytestring` refers to unicoding more information on this is found in [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

Before sending your code into sql make sure you decode it using `data.decode('utf-8')` That should remove the error you're having.